# jQuery Syntax with if block

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax

I'm trying to create an if block that spits out either a 3 or 4 based on screen width into a $postno variable. The 3 or 4 will mean that an $arg variable creates either 3 or 4 posts.

I've tried this but it's obviously wrong and I don't know the syntax as I'm still a bit of newbie. Can anyone help explain this? Thanks in advance.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => $postno,
);  

if($(window).width() >= 1024) {
$postno=4;

} 
else {
        $postno=3
    }
```

Comment: You're confusing PHP and jQuery together. PHP is a server side language, jQuery is browser side. PHP cannot tell what the width of the visitors window is unless you use jQuery to pass that value through using Ajax, etc.

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do here?  `$(window).width()` is not PHP.

Comment: I agree with @Karl, at any rate your code makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Mike Jackson Ask proper question. What you are exactly want to do?

Comment: I did say I was a newb! I am trying to get the value "3" if the screen width is over 1024 else I would like the value to be 4. Then I would like to insert that value into an $args PHP variable My code is obviously rubbish and doesn't work that is why I am here asking advice

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing PHP and jQuery together. PHP is a server side language, jQuery is browser side. PHP cannot tell what the width of the visitors window is unless you use jQuery to pass that value through using Ajax, etc.

Even then, if you're trying to use PHP to limit the block to 3 or 4 you won't be passing the screen width through until AFTER the document has been loaded by the visitor.

Your best bet is to use jQuery to detect the screen width, as you did already `$(window).width()` then use CSS to hide/show the correct amount of blocks. This can be achieved with overflow, and/or display none/block.

Example:

```
var width = $(window).width();

if(width >= 1024) {
    $('.block-4').show();
} else if(width < 1024) {
    $('.block-4').hide();
}
```

This is a very rough example however, just to explain the logic of it to you and may not work in your environment.

EDIT:

Here's a working example of what you're trying to achieve with PHP and jQuery.

You're going to need two files:

**index.php:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();

    $.post("blocks.php", { width: width }).done(function(data) {
        $('.content').html(data); 
    });
});
```

**blocks.php**

```
<?php
    $width = $_POST['width'];
    if($width >= 1024) {
        echo '4';
    } else {
        echo '3';
    }
?>
```

So what this will do is post the users screen width to a PHP file called blocks.php, this PHP file will then return 4 or 3 depending on what the screen size was, then using jQuery it will update the contents of a class called "content" with either 4 or 3.

Comment: I'd rather not use CSS. As I think can be done the other way by just changing how posts are show via the 'posts_per_page' => '', parameter. So I'd like my if block to spit out the value "3" if the screen width is over 1024, otherwise I'd like it to be "4". I understand this may be a simple question, but I'm new to jQuery. As you can probably tell!

Comment: Well yes, it can be done. But PHP will either need to A) Spit all the blocks out, then you change which are visible using jQuery or B) Not spit any out, then you can do an Ajax call on document ready to a PHP file in order to send across the width and receive the correct amount of blocks, then update the page as a callback.